# Getting the coordinates of a button

Tags: java, android, coordinates

How do you get the coordinates (x,y) of **the corners** of a button.

I've tried getting the y value of the right top corner by: ***(yCordOfButton) - (heighOfButton/2)***...with that, it almost works but doesn't quite work the precise way I need it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the top left corner of the screen by using `View.getLocationOnScreen(int[])` and then you can use the height and width to get the other corners as needed. getLocationOnScreen is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getLocationOnScreen(int%5B%5D)).

Comment: thanks Nate...though, I'm using a different approach

Comment: No problem, out of curiosity, what approach are you using instead?

Comment: Well...my objective wasn't to get the coordinates, I had a problem with scaling the button on ontouch event and do something when the onup coordinates are within the range of the button...so i did something like this: if (event.getY()>Ycoord){
if(event.getY()<Ycoord+Ylen){
if (event.getX()>Xcoord){
if(event.getX()<Xcoord+Xlen){do something...where Ycoord and Xcoord r the coordinates of the button...and Ylen and Xlen are the width and length of the button... turned out, to make simple and work, I needed the button to be the only child within a parent...wish I could explain it simpler